# Count time difference between some date time in the future and the current time in Automate

Tags: automate

I am struggling to count the time difference between the next new year, 0 o'clock at January 1 and the current time and to obtain the number of days, hours, minutes and seconds.

According to the LlamaLabs help, `Now` gives a unix timestamp for the current time and `date()` a timestamp of for the specified time date.

However, computing the number of days, hours etc. in the obvious way from the timestamps doesn't yield the expected result.

I also don't find appropriate blocks for the flow.

How would you solve that in Automate?

Comment: "I am struggling to compte the time difference between the next new year, 0 at January 1 and the current time and to obtain the number of days, hours, minutes and seconds." I am struggling to understand this sentence especially the "0 at January 1". Can you explain it better with a more understandable example?

Comment: Changed to "0 o'clock at January 1". The beginning of the new year, but it should not really matter.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the steps described below.

**Explanation**

We add a variable called `nextyear` whose initial value is derived from extracting the year from the current date and time, then adding 1 to get next year (Step 1). We then parse it to a date (Step 2). We calculate the difference between the two date using `durationFormat` function (Step 3). Then, optionally display the result (Step 4).

1. Add `Variable set` block

   - Variable: `nextyear`
   - Value: `dateFormat(Now, "yyyy") + 1`
2. Add `Variable set` block

   - Variable: `nextyear`
   - Value: `dateParse(nextyear ++ "/01/01 00:00:00", "yyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss")`
3. Add `Variable set` block

   - Variable: `diff`
   - Value: `durationFormat(nextyear - Now, "dd H'h'm'm's's")`
4. (optional) Add `Toast show` block

   - Message: `diff`

   [image]